# Error when upgrading glass mapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, glass-mapper

Currently i have glass mapper v3 and in process of upgrading to latest glass mapper i.e. v4, however when i build the project its giving me following error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1705  Assembly 'Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc' with identity 'Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc, Version=4.2.1.188, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' with identity 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Comment: which Sitecore version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the table of support versions of MVC with Sitemap versions. 8.1 and 8.2 support 5.2 MVC.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

The latest glass mapper may not work with the older versions of Sitecore.

You can upgrade your MVC to 5.2 and add bindings to your web.config to make requests to 5.1 work on 5.2.

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```